# Pull a Row Value associated with the Max Value of a Column

Tags: sql

We have two tables that we'd like to join, one is a Users table and the other is a Subscriptions Table.

Users table stores columns like
• User ID
• Name
• Email
• Account Create Date

Every time a new user joins, a new row is added to this table.

Subscription table stories columns like
• Subscription ID
• User ID
• Subscription Created At
• Subscription Ended At
• Subscription Status

Every time a user RESUBSCRIBES a new row is added. Continuing on their existing subscription does not create a new row.

Our goal is create a query that returns the following columns
• User ID
• Email
• Account Create Date
• Subscription Status (Active/Canceled/NULL)

However, when we attempt to do the query below it returns multiple rows for creators that have multiple subscriptions.

```
 SELECT
       u.user_id,
       u.email,
       u.account_create_date
       s.subscription_status
    FROM
       users as u
    INNER JOIN
       subscriptions as s
       on s.user_id = u.user_id
```

How can we write a query where it pulls the Subscription Status for the Subscription with the Max Subscription Created At date?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Not sure if it is the best way. ;)

Join a subquery of the User ID and max Max Subscription Created At date and use that to filter only those results.

```
SELECT
   u.user_id,
   u.email,
   u.account_create_date
   s.subscription_status
FROM
   users as u
INNER JOIN
   subscriptions as s
   on s.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT s.user_id, 
   MAX(s.subscription_created_at) AS subscription_created_at
   FROM subscriptions 
   GROUP BY s.user_id) max_s
   ON max_s.user_id = s.user_id

WHERE s.subscription_created_at = max_s.subscription_created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way uses window functions:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.email, u.account_create_date
       s.subscription_status
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.user_id ORDER BY s.created_at DESC) as seqnum
      FROM subscriptions s
     ) s
     ON s.user_id = u.user_id AND s.seqnum = 1;
```